# Custom fields in Api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, validation

I want to write a post API for a customer who gives his details like name, address , pincode , contact, etc. From the dashboard the customer can add any field (even those other than the above listed) i.e dynamic attributes. Fields are therefore unknown to the Api whitelisting process (customer_add_params.permit{})

How to go about it?

Comment: How do you plan to store this attributes with unknown names in your db? Serialized? Document storage?

Comment: I will not be storing them. Its only meant for one time use.

Comment: I'm simply pushing data to IPFS and not storing on local db.

Comment: Did you consider just pushing un-permitted params (`params[:key]`)?

Comment: yes but is there not a way to make dynamic permission on the params?

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't make sense. If you don't know what the user is sending, then you cannot whitelist the params. How do you dynamically permit secure parameters? You can only allow everything with [`permit!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit-21) or just use the plain un-permitted params. From a security point of view permitting everything is as bad as using the plain, un-permitted params hash.

Comment: if we want to permit some data and leave the rest un-permitted then how do we do that?

Comment: How do you want to decide what to permit and what not to permit, if you the attribute names an unknown to you?

Comment: say i want to permit name and contact and rest is unpermitted. then how to write it in rails?

Comment: You question is not clear to me. Why permit `:name` and `:contact`, when everything else will be used un-permitted anyway. What is the benefit of permitting something and let everything else pass un-permitted? It is like asking Peter Parker and Tony Stark for their passport at the border, but allow all others to cross the border without a passport at all. Then there is no benefit in asking poor Peter and Tony...

Comment: thats hilarious! let me explain myself. i have a dashboard where the fields are name , contact and then there is a field say Address proof. and the customer has to write the proof he is giving and upload the corresponding document. now the user may upload anything from DL or Bank statement or something else. Also he can upload more than one document.

Comment: Your question isn't a good fit for SO. You need to research, try things, and then, when you have a problem with your code, ask a specific question about that problem. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use a nested permissions like this:

```
params.require(...).permit(
  :name, :contact, :proofs => [:description, :file]
)
```

Which will permit a `name`, a `contact` and an array that must be named `proofs` and in that array there are only the attributes `description` and `file` allowed.

---

From the docs of [`permit`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit) about nested parameters:

> You can also use permit on nested parameters, like:
>
> ```
> params = ActionController::Parameters.new({
>   person: {
>     name: 'Francesco',
>     age:  22,
>     pets: [{
>       name: 'Purplish',
>       category: 'dogs'
>     }]
>   }
> })
>
> permitted = params.permit(person: [ :name, { pets: :name } ])
> permitted.permitted?                    # => true
> permitted[:person][:name]               # => "Francesco"
> permitted[:person][:age]                # => nil
> permitted[:person][:pets][0][:name]     # => "Purplish"
> permitted[:person][:pets][0][:category] # => nil
> ```

Comment: Thanks it was really helpful